# How to expand documentation from the M-x minibuffer when using vertico?

Tags: minibuffer, doom, help, vertico

How to expand documentation or add a popup for an entry in the M-x minibuffer [**Edit**: when using vertico] ?

I only get to see a bit of the documentation of each entry and text-scale-decrease does not increase the number of visible characters, it just changes the font size.

Using C-h o and checking each enty separately is tedious compared to just adding more characters by diminishing the font or adding a floating popup.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What entries are you talking about?

Comment: @NickD Sorry, I am not familiar with the emacs packages I am using (I am using doom emacs), but I think the items I am referring to are from the vertico package. When I enable that package, I ge a list of possible commands that macth with the text input